# Mysql Query for implementing sql LIKE as sql IN

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a mysql query to do this :

I have a table : Core

```
id tag
1  GameAnimal
2  Game
3  AbstractGame
4  AbstractAnimal
5  GameAbstract
```

now i want a result to count values like

```
Game     : 4
Animal   : 2
Abstract : 3
```

I have done the similar using the in function of mysql like this:

```
select tag, count(*) as count from core where tag in('Game','Abstract') group by tag
```

which gave me result as

```
Game : 1
```

the above query matches the letters and then gives the response, as GameAnimal is not equal to Game its not been included in the result, no wildcards are usefull here.

If such query not possible then suggest me the way to do this in single query call.

Comment: Your idea of storing hierarchical data is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do it like this way (supposing you're able to build your query dynamically):

```
select 
  count(if(tag like '%Game%', 1, null)) AS Game_Count, 
  count(if(tag like '%Animal%', 1, null)) AS Animal_Count, 
  count(if(tag like '%Abstract%', 1, null)) AS Abstract_Count 
from 
  core
```

or use `union` syntax if you need to get result as a column (that will be useful when amount of tags will be large)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a TAGS table with all possible tags:

```
CREATE TABLE tags
    ( `tag` varchar(40))
;

INSERT INTO tags
    ( `tag`)
VALUES
    ('Game'),
    ('Animal'),
    ('Abstract');
```

Then all tags should be separated by comma:

```
id tag
1  Game,Animal
2  Game
3  Abstract,Game
4  Abstract,Animal
5  Game,Abstract
```

And now here is a query:

```
select tags.tag, count(*) from t 
join tags on FIND_IN_SET(tags.tag,t.tag)>0
group by tags.tag
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e867/2)

Comment: i have lot of data in it, i am not willing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(*) from `table` where tag like '%game%') as 'game', 
(SELECT count(*) from `table`  where tag like '%animal%') as 'animal', 
(SELECT count(*) from `table`  where tag like '%abstract%') as 'abstract'
```